# Question about the notation $X/A$ in topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation

In Hatcher, the notation $X/A$ as appearing in the following text is never defined:

> If $(X,A)$ is a CW Pair consisting of a cell complex $X$ and a subcomplex $A$, then the quotient space $X/A$ inherits a natural cell complex structure from $X$ [...]

My guess as to what this notation means is to identify everything in $A$ to a single point. This is just a guess though, is it correct?

Comment: I think it is a bit in bad taste to say Hatcher isn't defining things clearly here. He assumes familiarity with basic point-set topology, and he notes that $X/A$ is the quotient space of $X$ by the subcomplex $A$ - so if you don't know what a quotient space is, you should look this up. Informally, you can indeed think of this as identifying $A$ to a point.

Comment: From the intro of his book "In terms of prerequisites, the present book assumes the reader has some familiarity with the content of the standard undergraduate courses in algebra and point-set topology. In particular, the reader should know about quotient spaces, or identification spaces as they are sometimes called, which are quite important for algebraic topology. Good sources for this concept are the textbooks [Armstrong 1983] and [J ̈anich 1984] listed in the Bibliography."

Comment: It says explicitly "[...] then the **quotient space** $X/A$ [...]". In the future, try to look up keywords you don't understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $X/A$ is the space where you identify everything in $A$ to a single point, also known as the [quotient space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Quotient_space_in_topology) of $X$ by $A$.

Comment: In the future, I think it would be nice to try and reach 30 characters through legitimate means if you can...